# Email alert are not sending email to client in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-developer

We had an email alert that was executed if criteria meet when a specific record was created it was working well and suddenly now it not working I have downloaded the email log file and I don't see any records which are sent by the salesforce.

what else i can check here

It is working till 02/06/2023 after that it is not working, the record are created but salesforce is not sending email to client.

I have even checked the Email Deliverability settings and it has selected all Email.

I have also done Test Deliverability from that I have received the email.